# Android ListView visual error:Button overlap the TextView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with TextView and Button each row this is my layout content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is a screenshot which describe the error: http://it.tinypic.com/r/a47ho9/9

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a `FrameLayout` for the `ListView` row because it is difficult to position items in a `FrameLayout`. Just use one `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` and put your `TextView` and `Button` inside that.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use a RelativeLayout to place your widgets correctly I would say. And I would also recommend to try flattening your layout. It means that you should not nest so many layouts. It is a pretty simple thing to do in this case. You want to have as little nested layouts as possible when you build your ui to optimisee performance.

Try something like this instead, might not be exactly what you want but maybe helps you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background=""
                android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Medium text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can read more about optimising your layout here https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html